# Porque me hace un <li> de mas?

Tags: javascript, calendar

Quiero que el bucle recorra el número de días y me cree un li por cada uno, lo que me sucede es que me crea un li de mas, con un espacio vacío, la verdad no lo estoy pudiendo comprender.

```js
const currentDate = document.querySelector(".current-date");
daysTag = document.querySelector(".days");

let date = new Date(),
currYear = date.getFullYear(),
currMont = date.getMonth();

const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

const renderCalendar = ()=> {
    let lastDateOfMont = new Date(currYear, currMont + 1, 0).getDate();
    console.log(lastDateOfMont);
    let liTag="";
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= lastDateOfMont; i++) {
        liTag += `<li>${i}<li>`;
        
    }


    currentDate.innerText = `${months[currMont]} ${currYear}`;
    daysTag.innerHTML = liTag;
}

renderCalendar();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, initial-sacale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <p class="current-date"></p>
      <div class="icons">
          <span class="material-symbol-rounded">&lt;</span>
          <span class="material-symbol-rounded">&gt;</span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="calendar">
      <ul class="weeks">
        <li>sun</li>
        <li>mon</li>
        <li>tue</li>
        <li>wed</li>
        <li>thu</li>
        <li>fri</li>
        <li>sat</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="days">      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
    

    
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es muy sencillo, es porque cuando defines ``liTag += `<li>${i}<li>`;`` se te olvidó cerrar la etiqueta `li`, debería ser ``liTag += `<li>${i}</li>`;``. No te preocupes, es un error que muchos hemos cometido. Como el problema es un error de dedo, he votado para cerrar la pregunta por motivo de error tipográfico. Saludos!

Comment: jajajaj que verguenza por dios, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Solo sería corregir el string con el tag `<li>` cerrando la etiqueta `</li>`

```
...
for (let i = 1; i <= lastDateOfMont; i++) {
  liTag += `<li>${i}<li>`;   
}
..
```

Corrigiendo sería asi

```
...
for (let i = 1; i <= lastDateOfMont; i++) {
  liTag += `<li>${i}</li>`;   
}
...
```